# Center aligning SWF in Flash breaks video prompt request

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, swfobject

I'm using swfobject to inject my swf. My SWF basically initiates a webcam and prompts the user for access to the cam. Problem is whenever I center align the div that contains the swf object the Allow/Deny button seems to be unresponsive/not clickable. It's the oddest thing.

[Here is the site for you to view the coding.](http://cbcf.pilotinteractive.ca/)

Perhaps someone has had the issue issue previously.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the div centered now ? because I could not reproduce your error I was able to access the webcam. The only instance I came up with is when the security panel is not accessible if any part of the panel is not viewable by the screen (i.e you drag the browser window to the right)

Comment: @Phwd if you take a look at that link again its now centered but I've noticed that it only works if I set the page to overflow: hidden. As soon as I remove that (you can test it yourself by setting overflow: auto; with a tool like FireBug. Still the same issue and I really need to figure this thing out. Yikes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a version of Flash less than 10.3?

This was a known issue that I experienced too.

There is an explanation here http://blog.mightyverse.com/2011/07/when-you-cant-click-the-flash-player-allow-button/

btw, that's not my blog. :-)